# spring boot return does not change the url?

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am submitting a form which has dropdown list which is dynamically populated . After the data is submitted i am returning the same form, but the issue is the url is still the from processing controller because of which the dropdown list does not show any values. I tried using redirect but it is giving me errors.

My form processing url is /normal/process_form
after i hit the submit button i want the url to be
/normal/myform

but at the moment it is returning me the view for myfrom but the url remains /normal/process_form

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 @ModelAttribute("dropdownvalues")
    public List<Your Class> getReports() {
        return ...
    }
```

which makes the `dropdownvalues` available in your `thymeleaf` template and handle the setting values based on it.